# Связка маршрутной карты со ссылкой в html, css

Tags: jquery, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста! Как можно ссылку привязать к карте google maps, ну или какой нибудь другой поисковой карте, при открытие которой сразу указывалась место нахождение за ранее заданного определенного объекта? Может есть какая нибудь толковая информация?

На пример к этой ссылке:

```
<a href="">Как к нам проехать</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как бы у google maps есть возможность сохранить информацию в ссылку и передать ее стороннему лицу, достаточно просто открыть, если надо проложить нужный маршрут и нажать на кнопку ссылки:

[image]

А вообще вопрос немного не туда.

Comment: Вопрос! А для чего нужен вот этот HTML-код для добавления на веб-сайт ? И почему вопрос не много не туда?

Comment: Это скорее относится к умению работать с сервисом карт гугла, чем непосредственно к верстке html, css и тем более программированию на jquery. 
>  А для чего нужен вот этот HTML-код для добавления на веб-сайт ?
Он вставляет уже не просто ссылку, а окно с миникартой.